# django problem:captured parameter in parent urlconf , incude() and reverse match

Tags: django

If I want to have django app called app1 which can make a user post note to someone's page and to his/her own page.
And if the user is logged in ,no need using username in the url, but the username parameter in url can be acts as parent in urlconf.

To make it clear:
*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns(''

    #if registered user/anonymous user visit someone's page
    url(r'^/foo/users/(?P<username>\w+)/app1/',include('app1.urls', namespace='myapp1')),

    #if user is logged in in his own page 
    url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls', namespace='myapp1')), 
    ...
)
```

*app1/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # I expect this pattern receives the username parameter from above 
    url(r'^note/add/$', app1_views.add_note,
     name='add_note'),

    url(r'^note/add/$', app1_views.add_note,
    { 'username':None}, name='add_note_own'),
    ...
    ...    
)
```

*app1/views.py*

```
def add_note(request, username=None):
    ...
    ...
```

**First question**:
Now for example john is logged in and on jack's notes page john want to post a note.
I want to be able to do something like this or near something like this:

*template app1/notes.html*

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {%if in his/her own note page %}
        <a href="{% url add_note_own %}">add note</a> Expected generated url: www.domain.com/app1/add
    {%else}
        <a href="{ %url add_note %}">add note</a> Expected generated url: www.domain.com/foo/jack/app1/add
    {%endif%}
{% endif %}
```

Is this possible?

Another thing,
if john wrote note in jack's page, and django gives the note id == 3,
so to show that note, only these urls are valid:
www.example.com/foo/jack/app1/3
www.example.com/foo/app1/3 (if jack logged in)

**Second question:**
what I want to achieve is reverse match can accept captured parameter up to to the
parent urlconf when include() is involved in url configuration. 
Can this be done?

Or if you  get what I mean and can provide simpler solution , please do so :)
sorry if this post is confusing, I am confused myself.
Thanks alot for the patience.

I'm using django 1.2.5

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass an username, one example can be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # I expect this pattern receives the username parameter from above 
    url(r'^note/add/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$', app1_views.add_note, name='add_note'),

    # username is an optional argument, so no need to pass it
    url(r'^note/add/$', app1_views.add_note, name='add_note_own'),
)
```

and then in template:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if page.owner == request.user %}
      <a href="{% url add_note_own %}">add note</a>
    {% else %}
       <a href="{% url add_note request.user.username %}">add note to {{ request.user.username }}</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```